# best practice / structure PHP AJAX calls

Tags: php, ajax

This is a best practice / structure question:

I've built a mini cms and use AJAX to process the actions to the database (a/e/d items for example). The way I currently have this setup is a single process.php file with a `case` call and in the JQ AJAX call, I define the action as below:

```
$.post("inc/process.php", {page: "add_page", form:
$('#form').serialize(),}, function(data){...});
```

my question is, is using `case` and grouping these items on a single process.php file the best way to go about this, or should I be structuring this with Classes and functions to call the various actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to do it as you did because the code is reusable and therefore is easier to change. However, if the data transitioning gets a little larger, you would want to look at separating things a little more.